# what can i do whilst on the sick

Tags: sickness

I phoned in sick on the Monday complaining of a sickness bug, vomiting and stomach cramps, by Wednesday the sickness had gone off a little but not entirely.
On the Thursday I was scheduled for an interview for a senior post which I couldn't re-arrange.
I went to the interview still not well, that evening I was vomiting a little more but by the Friday it had almost gone.
will I get into trouble for being off sick and going to an interview???

Comment: This is a question best answered by your employer (try reaching out to HR, or look at your employee handbook or policies), since it's a matter of their policies. We can't tell you what will happen.

Comment: Was the interview an internal one with your existing employer or with another company?

Answer (score 7):

Not if you don't tell anyone.

if the interview was internal and someone asks you, just say you felt brave enough to risk it although you were not completely well, and had to recoup in the following days.

If the interview was external I don't see why your employer needs to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you may get in trouble for being off sick depends on your company's sick policy (i.e. whether you have enough available sick days for the days missed).

As for the interview, as long as your current company does not know about it you will not get in trouble for attending.